# convert string value to list

Tags: python, string, list

I checked for a similar question, but couldn't find an answer.

```
Fnactot = []
Fnacdebut = 0 
Fnacnombre = 4
Fnac = 0
Fnac1 = ['major lazer', 'goooya', 1000]
Fnac2 = ['phoenix', 'wolfgang', 1300]
Fnac3 = ['jain', 'makemba', 1150]
Fnac4 = ['dj shadow', 'aphex', 2100]

while Fnacdebut < Fnacnombre :
    Fnacdebut = Fnacdebut + 1
    fnac = 'Fnac'+str(Fnacdebut)
    print fnac
```

I'm sure the answer is REALLy easy.... but i'm scratching my head there..

I would like to print my lists Fnac1, Fnac2, ...... but i'm printing the string value of fnac = 'Fnac'+str(Fnacdebut) instead. 
How ca, i convert the string result of fnac back to the name of my lists...

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to generate variable names. It involves evaluating variable names using `eval` and it's bad practice.

Just create a coherent data set from the start

just use a list of lists:

```
fnac = [['major lazer', 'goooya', 1000],
['phoenix', 'wolfgang', 1300],['jain', 'makemba', 1150],['dj shadow', 'aphex', 2100]]
```

then:

```
for f in fnac:
    print(f)
```

or (to have better control on the display, and since there are integers in your lists you have to convert them to string):

```
for f in fnac:
    print(",".join(str(x) for x in f))
```

Comment: Hi Thanks ! Yes of thought of your answer already but my question is more general on understanding how i can get a string back to the name of a list.
I would like to understand how I can get :
print fnac > ['major lazer', 'goooya', 1000]
and not print fnac > Fnac1

Any idea ?

Comment: that's just bad practice. It leads to using `eval`, and it's a major security issue among other things.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a way to do that: `print(locals()[fnac])` will print the content of lists.

Still you're better off storing lists in an another list or tuple and print them by iterating over the new list:

```
fnacs = (['major lazer', 'goooya', 1000],
         ['phoenix', 'wolfgang', 1300],
         ['jain', 'makemba', 1150],
         ['dj shadow', 'aphex', 2100])

for i, fnac in enumerate(fnacs):
    print("Fnac%d" % i, fnac)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Fnactot = []
Fnacdebut = 0 
Fnacnombre = 4
Fnac = 0
Fnac1 = ['major lazer', 'goooya', 1000]
Fnac2 = ['phoenix', 'wolfgang', 1300]
Fnac3 = ['jain', 'makemba', 1150]
Fnac4 = ['dj shadow', 'aphex', 2100]

while Fnacdebut < Fnacnombre :
    Fnacdebut = Fnacdebut + 1
    fnac = 'Fnac'+str(Fnacdebut)
    print globals()[fnac]
```

This will do, but a better way would be:

```
lst1 = ['major lazer', 'goooya', 1000]
lst2 = ['phoenix', 'wolfgang', 1300]
lst3 = ['jain', 'makemba', 1150]
lst4 = ['dj shadow', 'aphex', 2100]
all_lists = [lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4]

for lst in all_lists:
    print lst
```